# python 3.5 range trouble

Tags: list, range, python-3.5

locations:[['120', '40', 'x1'], ['200', '50', 'x2'], ['150', '15', 'x3'], ['240', '60', 'x4'], ['260', '45', 'x5'], ['225', '15', 'x6'], ['273', '20', 'x7'], ['221', '5', 'x8'], ['345', '20', 'x9']]

rangee:[['100', '0', '60', '40', 'x1'], ['80', '10', '30', '5', 'x2'], ['120', '0', '25', '10', 'x3'], ['100', '10', '0', '40', 'x4'], ['70', '0', '10', '25', 'x5'], ['75', '10', '5', '10', 'x6'], ['75', '0', '0', '0', 'x7'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'x8'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'x9']]

```
 for a in range(int(locations[1][0])+int(rangee[1][0]),int(locations[1][0])-int(rangee[1][1])):

   print("x")
```

I have a locations list with integers.But when I execute this it wont work.Any idea why?

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the contents of `locations`, what's the content of `rangee`? Without that info we can only guess what's wrong...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Comment: ı edited the lists

Comment: locations[1][0] + rangee[1][0] > locations[1][0] - rangee[1][1] . range(x,y) would not return results if x > y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debug (_ this is not debugging, thats just print out and looking at it_) your data - yours is cryptic to no end:

Use

```
locations = [['120', '40', 'x1'], ['200', '50', 'x2'], ['150', '15', 'x3'], ['240', '60', 'x4'], ['260', '45', 'x5'], ['225', '15', 'x6'], ['273', '20', 'x7'], ['221', '5', 'x8'], ['345', '20', 'x9']]

rangee = [['100', '0', '60', '40', 'x1'], ['80', '10', '30', '5', 'x2'], ['120', '0', '25', '10', 'x3'], ['100', '10', '0', '40', 'x4'], ['70', '0', '10', '25', 'x5'], ['75', '10', '5', '10', 'x6'], ['75', '0', '0', '0', 'x7'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'x8'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', 'x9']]


from_loc = locations[1][0]
from_ran = rangee[1][0]
to_loc = locations[1][0]
to_ran = rangee[1][1]

print ( "from " , from_loc, " + " , from_ran, "     to: ", to_loc, " - " , to_ran )
```

Output:

```
('from ', '200', ' + ', '80', '     to: ', '200', ' - ', '10')
```

Test:

```
print ( range(280,190))
```

Output:

```
[]
```

==> Empty list - for descenting ranges you need to add ,-1 to it for steps:

```
print ( range(280,190,-1))
```

Output:

```
[280, 279, 278, 277, 276, ... , 192, 191]
```

It depends on your usecase, you might want to do something like:

```
one = 280
two = 190

print (range( min(one,two), max(one,two))) # will sort them correctly
```

Output : `[190, ..., 279]`

OR

```
print(range(one,two, 1 if one < two else -1))
```

Which will add the correct stepping to your range depending on its values.